# Same frame, same settings give me different time render each time I render it

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, light, path

I'm lost, I'm trying to find the good light path bounces settings for decrease the render time and keep a good result, but with the same settings if I render the same frame many times I get different time rendering.
For example:
first time: 3.23.35
second time:3.46.18
third time: 3.20.21

The result image is perfectly the same but the time render defer alot.

It's so weird! What's happening here?!
I'm using blender 2.91 with cycles on a  macbook pro 16" with i9 8 core 32 gb ram rendering on only cpu (with blender my radeon is not supported)

Comment: Are there any other tools running? Suggest monitor ram and cpu while rendering

Comment: I have a second monitor but during this test I'm doing nothing on the computer just wainting in front of :)

Comment: There are usually a lot of apps running in the background :)

Comment: I tried to detach the second monitor and close all softwares but still have different time render, firsti s 3.08 the second time 3.15, so weird

Comment: You can not quit *all* apps in OSX... open up the ressource monitor https://superuser.com/questions/10470/resource-monitor-for-os-x

Comment: I tried to link off my bluettoh keyboard and my mouse but sitll have different time, now is 3.19.13 min uffff

Comment: Ok I’ve checked during the rendering I have less than 10 apps using cpu but less than 1% each one

Comment: So I swithced of also the wifi and closed abobe creative cloud, still different time render but at least the difference between each render is just few seconds